# Accessing and executing function in child class from base class

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to access child class members and execute child function from base class?

For example:

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass {

    protected childMember = 'someName';

    constructor() {
        super();
        super.runBaseFn();
    }

    runChildFn() {
        console.info('child fn');
    }
}

class BaseClass {

    runBaseFn() {
       if (child.childMember === 'someName') {
           child.runChildFn();
       }
    }
}
```

Is this possible to accomplish the code in `runBaseFn`? Or any similar solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to declare that in the parent class:

```
class BaseClass {
    protected childMember: string;

    runBaseFn() {
       if (this.childMember === 'someName') {
           this.runChildFn();
       }
    }

    protected runChildFn() {}
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.childMember = 'someName';
        super.runBaseFn();
    }

    runChildFn() {
        console.info('child fn');
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20BaseClass%20%7B%0D%0A%09protected%20childMember%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%20%20%20%20runBaseFn()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.childMember%20%3D%3D%3D%20'someName')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.runChildFn()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09protected%20runChildFn()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ChildClass%20extends%20BaseClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09this.childMember%20%3D%20'someName'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super.runBaseFn()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20runChildFn()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.info('child%20fn')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D))

You can make the parent class `abstract`:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    protected childMember: string;

    runBaseFn() {
       if (this.childMember === 'someName') {
           this.runChildFn();
       }
    }

    protected abstract runChildFn();
}
```